# how to trigger Jenkins job from ant script running on same Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, ant

I'm running an ant job that runs several thing on master node and need to trigger several jobs on slave servers based on the options i select from the main job parameters

is there a way to call another job from within ant script without using jenkins-cli.jar as external command

Comment: Well usally you use jenkins and not Ant to do such things for you.
You can have different post build action to start different jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Jenkins jobs by doing an HTTP request:

1. Go to your Job Configuration
2. Build triggers > Check 'Trigger Builds Remotely' and think of an access token, e.g. SOME_SECURE_TOKEN.
3. In your ant script: execute a `POST` request to `JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build?token=SOME_SECURE_TOKEN`

Note that if you have authentication in place, you need to set up a user who is authorized to start the other jobs. In that case read this more detailed explanation: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/

Another solution would be to use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to trigger builds from a Jenkins step. You mention that the jobs that need to be triggered may depend on the job parameters. In that case you can combine the [Conditional Buildstep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin with the Parameterized Trigger plugin.